# Image not found on dompdf

Tags: php, html, image, dompdf

I set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` to true. When I create a `PDF` on my local. It is working and image is appearing on `PDF`. But when I create this on a `server`, image is not appeared.

Error is `Image no found`

Comment: Check if path to a file is correct, if your script has permission to read image and so on.

Comment: Where is located the image? Can you access it without login information?

Comment: What is the full URL of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the base_path of your application.
have you set the base_path before at dompdf.php?
set the parameter with "dirname(**FILE**)"
so even if you use local or server it doesn't matter for you